# Failed validation from email input is erasing contents of a different text area ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

A modal I am working on has some very strange behavior when testing. When the "Email" field fails validation, it clears the "Comment" text area, but leaves all other inputs alone and does not clear them.

Below is the modal page:

```
    @model Project_Name.ViewModels.ProspectViewModel
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="add-prospect" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addProspectLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form asp-action="Prospect">
                <input name="IsValid" type="hidden" value="@ViewData.ModelState.IsValid.ToString()" />
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="addContactLabel">Add Prospect</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="firstName"></label>
                        <input asp-for="firstName" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="firstName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="lastName"></label>
                        <input asp-for="lastName" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="lastName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="companyName"></label>
                        <input asp-for="companyName" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="companyName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="email"></label>
                        <input type="email" asp-for="email" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="email" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="cellPhone"></label>
                        <input type="tel" asp-for="cellPhone" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="cellPhone" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="comment"></label>
                        <textarea asp-for="comment" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="comment" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-save="modal">Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the model it uses, if that helps:

```
public class ProspectViewModel
    {
        public ProspectViewModel() 
        {
        }

        public Guid id { get; set; }
        public string userId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
        public string companyName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is Required")]
        [Display(Name ="First Name")]
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is Required")]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string email { get; set; }
        [Phone]
        [Display(Name = "Cell Phone")]
        public string cellPhone { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Note")]
        public string comment { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Connect Meeting")]
        public DateTime? meetingDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
        public string createdBy { get; set; }
        public bool isActive { get; set; }

    }
```

Ive cant seem to find any other info on this issue. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Here is the controller code that opens and posts the modal:

```
public IActionResult Prospect()
        {
            var model = new ProspectViewModel();

            return PartialView("_AddProspect", model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Prospect(ProspectViewModel model)
        {
            if(model.email == null && model.cellPhone == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("email", "Email or Cell Phone is required!");
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);

                var user = User.Identity.Name;
                var prospect = _mapper.Map<Prospect>(model);
                prospect.createdDate = DateTime.Now;
                prospect.createdBy = user;
                prospect.modifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
                prospect.modifiedBy = user;
                prospect.userId = userId;
                prospect.isActive = true;
                _unitOfWork.Prospects.Add(prospect);
                _unitOfWork.Complete();

                TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "Prospect successfully added!";
            }

            return PartialView("_AddProspect", model);
        }
```

Comment: Do you have front-end js code involved in verification? If not, it is recommended to update this part of the back-end code in the post.

Comment: There are no custom validation scripts. What back-end do you mean? The controller method that is called?

Comment: Yes, I just want reproduce your issue.

Comment: Ok I edited the original post.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm still unsure WHY it did this, but it appears that since the "comment" field was a text-area element and not an input, and every failed validation of the other input fields would clear the text-area but not the other inputs. When I changed the  element to be an , it stopped clearing on other inputs' failed validation.